# My Ajax script and event object somehow does not prevent the load

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am currently using AJAX to actually make my website more dynamic. But somehow the event objects method e.preventDefault() does not fire to prevent the link to load. I have specified a container which will be replaced, now I don't know the reason for this failure. Through the .load method I am loading HTML content, to be exact the content from another 'container' in the HTML.

My index.php:

```
<nav>
    <a class = "current" href="index.php">Home</a>
    <a href="search.html">Search</a>
</nav>
<div class="header">
    <header class="title">jrr scientists - Official</header>
    <img id="logo" height="100" width="160" src="Logo/dev.png">


</div>
<section id="content">
    <div id="container">
    <div class="img2">
        <img id="ish"src="img/ish.jpg">
        <img id="mit" src="img/it.png"><br>
        <img width="100" height="100" id="home" src="img/toys1.jpg">
        <img width="200" height ="100" src="img/This is CS50.gif"> <br><br> <br><br> 
        <p> This is supposed to be a small thank you to all these institutions to make </p>
        <p> education accessable worldwide, even to  non-college students. Therefore material </p>
        <p> will be pblished here to enhance the use of this education. </p>
        <p> *********************************************************************************************** </p>
        <p> *********************************************************************************************** </p>
        <p> From the Editor JRR - Jayant Raul Rao </p>

    </div>


    <div id="text">
    <p> This is the official website of jrr developer and the </p>
    <p> CS environment to make your life easier. This website</p>
    <p> will focus on programming and computer science introducing </p>
    <p> concepts, displaying offical documentations and scripts </p>
    <p> from various examples. We can actually have a look at </p>
    <p> Google Scholar pdf's and a lot of facts of cs, maths </p>
    <p> and physics undermining the determination and will to </p>
    <p> save and keep data in a way to help. This page will be </p>
    <p> empowered by different features like a search engine, </p>
    <p> CS50 lectures, Google Scholar texts and maths problems. </p>
    <p>********************************************</p>
    <p>                JRR (Jayant Raul Rao)                    </p>
    </div>



    <div id="img">
    <img  class= "img" width="200" height="120" src="img/ibm.jpg">
    <img  id = "img1" width="190" height="120" src="img/term.png"> <br>
    <img  id="xcode"width="80" height="70" src="img/xcode.png">
    </div>
</div>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/basis.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/ajax.js"></script>
```

Now here I will replace the container through this jQuery script (ajax.js)
:

```
$('nav a').on('click', function(e) {                 // User clicks nav link
  e.preventDefault();                                // Stop loading new link
  var url = this.href;                               // Get value of href

  $('nav a.current').removeClass('current');         // Clear current indicator
  $(this).addClass('current');                       // New current indicator


  $('#container').remove();                          // Remove old content
  $('#content').load(url + ' #container').hide().fadeIn('fast'); // New content
});
```

After this I will load this and replace the old container with the new one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
<section id = "content"> 
<div id="container">
<!-- <img src="toys1.jpg" /> -->
<div id="header">
            <img class="pio"alt="CS50 Search" src="img/Unknown.gif"/>
        </div>

<form action="https://www.google.com/search" method="get">
     <input class="t" name="q" type="text"/><br/>
     <button class="u">Search</button>
</form>

</div>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/ajax.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: check firebug..there must be some error..

Comment: This highly depends on the browser you are using, I would for a first, try to add ```return false;``` at the end of the callback.

Comment: I checked in Chrome Inspector, Firefoxs Firebug and there is currently 00       errors

Comment: I tried in the latest versions of Safari, Chrome, Firefox, transmitted it to my other web server on my PC ran it on IE and it also didn't work.

Comment: can you create a https://jsfiddle.net that shows the actual problem ?

Comment: I checked already there and every other possibility before questioning here in StackOverflow.